# How to use a JCEKS Keystore in Python for AES Encryption?

Tags: python, encryption, aes, jceks, pyjks

I have a JCEKS file that contains a secret entry. I'm supposed to use this secret entry from the key store and use that to perform an AES encryption using Python.

I was able to load the KeyStore file in Python using the pyjks library in Python.

I'm able to view my secret entries by trying the following -

```
import jks

key_store = jks.KeyStore.load("path/to/keystore", "keystorepass")

key_store.entries
```

which return the following value

```
{
    'mysecretentry': <jks.jks.SecretKeyEntry at 0x7fd676e65130>
}
```

But I'm not sure how to access this key so that I can use this as my key in AES encryption

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

cipher = AES.new(mysecretentry, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```

Comment: There is a simple example: "import jks" "keystore = jks.KeyStore.load('keystore.jks', 'passphrase')" "print(keystore.secret_keys)" - the printout is the key (as it should be random it is not really "printable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the secure key stored in the Keystore by simply

```
secure_key = key_store.entries['mysecretentry'].__getattr__('key')
```

This would return something like -

```
b"^\x88H\x98\xda(\x04qQ\xd0\xe5o\x8d\xc6)'s`=\rj\xab\xbd\xd6*\x11\xefr\x1d\x15B\xd8"
```

The above `secure_key` can be used for AES Encryption

Comment: Why not use the [API](https://pyjks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jks.html) as designed?